# I want to print associative array values

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Im doing homework that consist on a basic validation of user and password on php. I have an one-dimensional associative array. I can print the value when the condition is true, but i can not print only one "else" because the "if" is in a foreach

Content of php:

```
<?php 

    $error = 0;
    $mensajeError = "";

    $login = array('pepe' => 'pepon', 'maria' => 'mary', 'manolo' => 'manolito');

    if (!isset($_POST['user']) || $_POST['user'] == "") {
        $error++;
        $mensajeError .= "El usuario no puede quedar vac&iacute;o";
    }


    if (!isset($_POST['pass']) || $_POST['pass'] == "") {
        $error++;
        $mensajeError .= "<p>La contraseña no puede quedar vac&iacute;a</p>";
    }

    if ($error > 0)
    {
        echo $mensajeError;
    }

    else
    {

        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        foreach ($login as $clave => $valor) 
        {

            if ($user == $clave && $pass == $valor) {
                $user = $clave;
                $pass = $valor; 
                echo "Hola " . $user . ", bienvenido a la aplicación";
            }

            if ($user != $clave && $pass != $valor) {
                echo "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos";  
            }


        }



    }

?>
```

Comment: `if ($user == $clave && $pass == $valor) {
                $user = $clave;
                $pass = $valor;` I think you have to think about DRY(Dont repeat yourself) - there is no need to assign the same value to variables.

Comment: This looks unsafe to use, being what appears to be plain text passwords. Any special reason you're not using a database and a safe password hashing method?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Most probably it is not in the homework's scope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a loop at all, all you need to do is check if there is an array entry with the user name (using `isset()`) and also this entry has the same password...

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if (isset($login[$user]) && $pass == $login[$user]) {
    echo "Hola " . $user . ", bienvenido a la aplicación";
}
else    {
    echo "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos";
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the far more practical approach! I'd delete my answer but I can't delete accepted answers 

Answer (score 1):

This answer specifically explains how to check for "any" truth values. In this particular question's case of checking for a single matching index and indexing with that, [Nigel Ren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58438366/1092820) is more practical.

---

Use a flag to check if any match occurs, and if none are after the `foreach` then reject:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$success = False;

foreach ($login as $clave => $valor) 
{
    if ($user == $clave && $pass == $valor) {
        $success = True;
        echo "Hola " . $user . ", bienvenido a la aplicación";
    }
}

if (!$success) {
    echo "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos";  
}
```